# About applying Abel theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Here I apply abel convergence theorem to a problem.

Abel theorem: If $\sum a_nx^n$ converges to $f(x)$ for $|x|<1$ and $\sum a_n$ converges then $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}f(x)=\sum a_n$

My apply: $\sum a_nx^n$ converges to $f(x)$ for $|x|<1$ then put $y=-x$ we have $\sum (-1)^na_ny^n$ converges to $f(-y)$ for $|y|<1$. Then if $\sum (-1)^na_n$ converges we can conclude that $\lim_{y\rightarrow 1}f(-y)=\sum (-1)^na_n$ or:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -1}f(x)=\sum (-1)^na_n$$

Is it true?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is false.

Consider the Taylor series for $\log(1+x)$ at $x = 0$, which has, I believe, $a_n = (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{n}$. This converges at $x = 1$ (to $\ln 2$, if I've got things right) but not at $x = -1$ (where it amounts to the sum of the harmonic series).

Your statement might be correct if you assume all the $a_i$ are non-negative. Then absolute converge implies convergence, and you'd be OK.

Comment: if $\sum (-1)^na_n$ converges then I can conclude. In this case I believe that the harmonic series does not converge, therefore my argument does not apply

Comment: I missed your "if $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ converges" statement...apologies. The remainder of your argument looks just fine, so I would say that your application was correct, yes.

Comment: thanks. I'm new to Abel theorem and sometimes I don't know why it states only for the limit to $1$ not to $-1$

Comment: I'm guessing the reason is simplicity: To state it for both ends, you'd have to say "...then this limit, if it exists, is $\sum a_n$, and THIS limit, if it exists, is $\sum (-1)^n a_n$." That's a little awkward, so it's stated in the simpler form, and your idea is used to prove the other case as a corollary, or exercise, or something like that.